# Application User Preferences and Doman Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm somewhat new to Domain Driven Design and have coded up our core business processes and objects in our Domain Layer.  The domain objects are being persisted through Repositories, and everything fits really well.  The domain model and services are exposed to the front end via web / WCF services.

I'm starting to work on parts of the front end, and have some front end settings and concepts that need to be persisted, like saving user layouts, views, and preferences.  Originally, I just had these models coded up in the front end assembly (I'm using WPF). I'm trying to figure out how these application objects fit into the existing domain model and repositories.  Other than using the same User object, the application model concerns seem completely unrelated to the existing domain model.  I'm wary of overengineering the solution, but it feels like I should create a sort-of mini-domain model and respository for the application objects.  Should I create a separate set of assemblies/libraries to manage the application models or is there a better approach?  Thanks!

Comment: In the end, it's up to you how you define what's part of the Domain Model and what's not; based on my experience, I'd say a flexible approach gets you there more often than not.

Comment: Are these objects(preferencec views) related to your business core domains? If not, you'd better not mix them with your domain models. Search "bounded context" for how to handle this case.

Comment: While the domain level services and models will likely be used in multiple application contexts, the preferences and views are specific to the primary application being built.  The user is the only real shared object between the application preferences and the domain layer.  I guess it makes sense to separate the application models from the rest of the domain model, and I'll figure out whether or not to have the application model refer to the domain model's user class or define its own more application-centric user class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Keep your core domain small and focused.